# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.postgresql.Driver)

Tags: java, heroku

Created a web app using maven and deployed it on heroku. Everything works find but when I call a action that uses the postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4 driver I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.postgresql.Driver)
```

I know that the problem is I'm using jdk 7 on my development environment and a lower version is running on heroku (at least I think so). My first question is, why does the other actions don't give this error only actions that uses postqresql driver gives this problem the rest of the app works just fine? The other thing I did was download jdk 6 and then added it to my project build path, then configure eclipse compiler compliance to 1.6 but even then I have the same problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you actually rebuild/compile your project, or just re-ran it with changing configuration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to use a copy of the database driver that is compiled for JDK 6.

It seems that you are not getting the problem with your application code because your build changes worked.  (Specifically the change to the compliance level.  I don't think adding a JDK to the (regular) build path will make any difference.)

But of course, that won't make any difference for the database driver ... because you are not compiling that.

---

However, according to [the download page](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html), postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4 is supposed to be compatible with Java 6 as well as 7.  So maybe you've gotten the JAR from somewhere else ... or by compiling from source with a Java 7 target.

**UPDATE** - I can confirm that the JAR on the download site has a Driver class whose bytecode version is 50.0 not 51.0.  I suggest you download and use a fresh copy from there.

Comment: Or get the source (if it's available) for the driver and compile it yourself with target java 6.

Answer (score 20):

For java 6 use:

```
postgresql-9.2-1004-jdbc4.jar 
postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc4.jar
```

For java 7 use:

```
postgresql-9.2-1004-jdbc41.jar 
postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar
```

Comment: This works, thank you! (My complier is 1.6 and I use postgresql-9.2-1004-jdbc4.jar )

Answer (score 9):

If you are using maven, the [9.2-1002-jdbc4 version](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002-jdbc4/) on central repository has been compiled using 1.7 target. Use previous version until it has been fixed.

Comment: Just for reference: The previous version in the central repository would be postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4 (note the different groupId)

Answer (score 7):

It seems that this has been resolved with the latest build ID 1003:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to Install Higher Version of java that your Application Compile with and suppose if i have Application with compile with Jre 1.6 then i need 1.6 or Higher Version of Jre 1.6 and ya one thing is that

or

Just Compile your Class file i mean your application.java file with Default Jre that you have Available with java and Just Run on the same.

or Third Option.

Download that JRE and install that JRE version in your Machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem and also the ClassNotFoundException for loading JDBC driver problem. The solution is to get the correct version of the postgres jar from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#jdbcselection. If you are using Maven, add the version of your dependency accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to swapping out your Java 6-incompatible Postgres driver for an alternative  Java 7-friendly version (as recommended by most of the other answers) is to have Heroku use Java 7 to compile and run your application. If you're using JDK 7 for development, as you say, this might help avoid other incompatibilities.

To do this, follow [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app) on Heroku Devcenter. Here's a summary:

1. Create a file named `system.properties` in your app's base directory.
2. Add the property `java.runtime.version=1.7` to the file, i.e.:

   ```
   java.runtime.version=1.7
   ```
3. Commit the `system.properties` file and push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue

On this page - http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Section -  Current Version

Details about jvm versions and postgres jdbc drivers helped me figure it out.